# Getting TypeError fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression, lmfit

I'm trying to use Simple Linear regression `lm.fit()` but getting this error:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Code:

```
lm = LinearRegression

x = df[['battery_power']]

y = df['price']

lm.fit(X=x, y=y)
```

Comment: I can't quite find good documentation on what you're using. However, just by looking at it, I'd assume `lm = LinearRegression` needs to be instantiated `lm = LinearRegression()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is
`lm = LinearRegression`
But this does not create a **LinearRegression** instance. instead, you are just making    another way to call the **LinearRegression** class.
What you need to do is this:
`lm = LinearRegression()` With parenthesis.

In general, you should know that A *missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'* error means that you are not passing an instance of the class. probably because you did not create one or the variable you are calling the method with is not an instance of the class.

So this is your code:

```py
lm = LinearRegression()

x = df[['battery_power']]

y = df['price']

lm.fit(X=x, y=y)
```